# Speed/efficiency tradeoff with String.length() and string.toCharArray().length

Tags: java, arrays, string, performance, char

I have a method that accepts a `String` parameter. I need to convert my `String` to a `char[]` for processing. However, if my String is greater than a certain length, I can stop processing my method logic.

```
public void doSomething(String str) {
  char[] strArray = str.toCharArray();
  // do something
}
```

I know that in terms of space efficiency, I should just check `str.length()` before creating my `char[]`. However, this got me thinking. In terms of time complexity, which is more efficient assuming I needed the `char[]` anyways?

Assuming I already have two objects `String` and `char[]`, which is faster/more efficient?

1. `str.length()`
2. `strArray.length`

Comment: @yshavit You are correct. I am wrong.

Comment: @yshavit: So they stopped sharing char arrays in Java 8?

Comment: @AaronDigulla They stopped doing that half way through 7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you have both objects already, the time complexity is the same: it's O(1), because both `java.lang.String` and Java arrays store their length for direct retrieval.

However, you can improve upon the timing of your method by using [`getChars` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getChars%28int,%20int,%20char%5B%5D,%20int%29) of the string to avoid copying the characters past the end of the substring that you need:

```
int maxLength = 100;
int effectiveLength = Math.min(maxLength, str.length());
char[] strArray = new char[effectiveLength];
str.getChars(0, effectiveLength, strArray, 0);
```

If it happens that your algorithm can stop processing before reaching the end of the string, this approach would let you avoid allocating the extra memory and copying the characters into it.

Answer (score 7):

That depends on how the method is implemented and the Java API gives no guarantees for that.

The current implementation is that `toCharArray()` will give you a copy of the String's underlying buffer, so it's a very expensive operation (memory allocation + copy many bytes), especially compared to `str.length()` which just returns the value of an internal `final` field (at least in Java 6).

In Java 7+, they seem to have stopped sharing the underlying character array (now, `substr()` always makes a copy).

Comment: The OP makes fairly clear they're already calling `toCharArray()`, and doing it only once; this seems irrelevant.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Nope: "I should just check str.length() **before** creating my char[]."

Comment: @clcto: Your edit is wrong. `String.length()` does **not** return the length of the underlying `char` array.

Comment: @AaronDigulla my edit was just adding a "`" at the end of str.length()

Comment: @AaronDigulla i did. "Added one character in body." check the markdown edit history.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I updated my answer. Java 6 uses different code.

Comment: I was always under the impression that `length()` depended on the encoding.

Comment: [Here](http://java-performance.info/changes-to-string-java-1-7-0_06/) are the changes.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: That depends. length() gives you the number of 16bit characters. But some of them are merged when the String is printed using a Unicode font, so there is `codePointCount()` which gives you the number of "real" Unicode characters.

Comment: Yeah, that's where my confusion was.